# How to use encoding with NSString?

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6

Are there any solution to use encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding in this code:

```
NSString *aa = [[theNews objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"Title"];
    cell.titleLabel.text = [aa encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Because I have this result

```
"&#1578;&#1580;&#1575;&#1585;&#1576; &#1603;&#1578;&#1575;&#1576;&#1577; &#1576;&#1575;&#1604;&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1610;";
```

This is arabic words

"تجارب كتابة بالعربي"

Comment: Where is the `encoding:` method coming from, because it isn't part of NSString.

Comment: [aa encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; I know it's wrong so I ask for a way :)

Comment: The thing is that you are assigning creating a string and then trying to send it the encoding message, which it won't respond to. I'm surprised this even compiled cleanly. Why aren't you just using the string? What are you trying to accomplish by messing with the encoding.

Answer (score 2):

"&#1578;" is not UTF-8 encoded. It is XML-encoded as entities. The UTF-8 version of that is 2 bytes long (0x06 followed by 0x2A). Yours is a 7-character string.

The tool you want is CFXML:

```
NSString *
arabic = CFBridgingRelease(CFXMLCreateStringByUnescapingEntities(NULL,
                                                                 (__bridge void*)string,
                                                                 NULL));
```